# Python Versions -- Python3 vs Python and pyenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyenv

When I type

```
python3 --version
```

I get

```
Python 3.11.4
```

When I type

pyenv versions

I get

```
 system
  3.7.17
  3.9.17
  3.10.12
```

Why the disrepancy? I want to use 3.9.0

Comment: Also, why would you want to use 3.9.0 when that's not even the latest 3.9.x patch version?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is not to use pyevn, but to use a virtual env.  You will have to activate this python environment whenever you want to switch over, but that way you can keep your 3.9 requirements localized instead of trying to switch you primary python3 from the system default.

Here is an example:

```py
$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.4
$ python3.9 -m venv mypy3venv # creates a virtual env under ./mypy3venv
$ . mypy3venv/bin/activate
$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.17
```

Comment: `pyenv` and virtual environments are not mutually exclusive. `pyenv` is used to manage the set of Python versions *available* for use in creating virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

`python3` look like system level python configured.

`pyenv` is python manager, which is showing that you have these various python versions install under pyenv.

to use python 3.9 using pyenv, you need to set it to global or local state using command  `pyenv global 3.9.17` . this will make python3.9.17 as system level default python environment